# Unity Player instantiating using photon pun 2

Tags: unity-game-engine, photon

I am instantiating 2 players in game scene using photon pun 2 all i want is if player's local num is 1 it should instantiate in blue spot also if player's local num is 2 it should also instantiate in blue spot but both players should see each other at red spot as enemy

```
void CreatePlayer(){

int localPlayerActorNumber = PhotonNetwork.LocalPlayer.ActorNumber;
if(localPlayerActorNumber==1){
 PhotonNetwork.Instantiate("Player2",SpawnPointManager.Instance.SPone[0].position, SpawnPointManager.Instance.SPone[0].rotation, 0 , new object[] {Pv.ViewID});
}
else if(localPlayerActorNumber==2){
PhotonNetwork.Instantiate("Player2",SpawnPointManager.Instance.SPone[0].position, SpawnPointManager.Instance.SPone[0].rotation, 0 , new object[] {Pv.ViewID});
}


 }
```